# How to apply incrementing numbers from strings (invoice numbers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement incrementing invoice numbers on my current application, however I am confused as to how to go about it as the applications invoices are a string.

Currently the invoice numbers look like this: `Q20140001` and they are supposed to increase by 1 for each new invoice (so the next invoice number would be `Q20140002`). 
All I would like to do is split the string ( in to `Q` and `20140001`). Then I would like to have the `20140001` number increment to `20140002`.

My guess is that every time I want to create a new number, I check the last invoice number that was stored on the database, parse it into a string and an integer, take the integer and increment it by 1, and then add the Q back on to it.

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, though.

Comment: I think it's correct, but not very efficient. Do you have to increment always the same number, or do you might have to increment any in your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you  tried using the `String#succ` method?

IRB session:

```
2.1.2 :001 > 'Q20140001'.succ
 => "Q20140002"
2.1.2 :002 >
```

One thing you must keep in mind is, that after 99999999 invoices, the result *may* not be what you want:

```
2.1.2 :002 > 'Q99999999'.succ
 => "R00000000"
2.1.2 :003 >
```

`Q` will be incremented to the next ASCII position `R`, resulting in `R00000000`. One possible solution is to fill the invoice number with enough zeros, something like: `Q00000000020140001` or leave the things as they are, which may be better in the long run.

Comment: Or just `str = 'Q99999999'; str[0]+str[1..-1].succ #=> "Q100000000"`, but if that were my company, I don't think I'd care. Oh, wait!, we have `str = 'Z99999999` to worry about.